# Macro that can transpose row data into specific column formats

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a macro that can transpose data into a new sheet with a specific format.

The data can be pasted into Sheet 1 and once the macro is run, it should transpose that data correctly as per the format in Sheet 2 (including cell sizes, fonts, etc.) I have created a sample of the sheet, but don't know how to code it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can download the file from this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5ixqk5woW4LVhfMnFPcmNsZDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Where is the code?

Comment: Hi Kathara, I'm not competent enough to code from scratch. I've never learnt coding, the only amount of coding I know is editing or restructuring the code to suit my needs. Until now, I never needed to create something so unique.

Comment: You might not get any help if you don't try something. Stackoverflow is to help you with struggles that you come across with your code. Have you at least read a little about vba? What are the criterias of the data that will be copied? Google "VBA .copy Method" and "VBA .paste Method" for the beginning. And maybe Google "Ron de Buin" as he has some tipps regarding VBA in Excel.

Comment: also there should be a method called .pastespecial. Have you formatted the second sheet as you wish it to be? If yes then you could copy a range from sheet 1 to sheet 2 with Pastespecial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839476.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Kathara, I tried to code a lot of it before manu gave his solution below. I just got to the point where I was able to automate the barcode being created, but I have a better understanding of vba thanks to you. This is how far I got (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5ixqk5woW4MGtEeE8tNWt1R0U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: always happy to help. I had to learn vba by myself as well, so I know the struggles but exactly that is stackoverflow for. They can help you when you get stuck. If you need help again, don't hesitate to ask a question (this time with your code snippet ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be a very good start to what you want to do. I took as example the picture that you attached. So I respect the column and so on...

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, a As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of your sheet where there is all data
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Change the name of your sheet where you want to past

Lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

j = 1 ' Start to column A
a = 1 ' Start to row 1

For i = 2 To Lastrow

        ws1.Cells(i, 1).Copy 'ItemCode
        ws2.Cells(a, j).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

        ws1.Cells(i, 2).Copy ' ItemSku
        ws2.Cells(a + 1, j).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

        ws1.Cells(i, 4).Copy ' VendorSkuCode
        ws2.Cells(a + 2, j).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

        ws1.Cells(i, 5).Copy 'ItemSize
        ws2.Cells(a + 3, j).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

        ws1.Cells(i, 6).Copy 'ItemColor
        ws2.Cells(a + 4, j).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

        ws1.Cells(i, 7).Copy 'mrp
        ws2.Cells(a + 5, j).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

        ws2.Cells(a + 6, j) = "*" & ws1.Cells(i, 1) & "*" 'ItemCode

     j = j + 2 ' Go to 2 columns on the right

     If j > 7 Then ' If j is in Column G then
        a = a + 8 ' Go to 9 row below
        j = 1 ' Reset the column to column A
    End If


Next i

End Sub
```